# Copying an image in Mac OS X 1000 times

Tags: macos, copy, duplicates

When I do a simple copy or duplicate from the Finder the duplicate of, say "1.jpg" is renamed "1 copy.jpg" Is there a simple way, using some scripting language, to take "1.jpg" and make 1000 copies, each named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg...1000.jpg?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean 999 times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Terminal, run this (or save it as a .sh script and run that):

```
for i in {2..1000}; do cp 1.jpg $i.jpg; done
```

Answer (score 0):

sh:

```
for f in `seq 2 1000`; do cp 1.jpg $f.jpg; done
```

Comment: osx does not come with seq by default;

Comment: That's...ridiculous.  It's part of GNU coreutils.

Comment: OSX doesnt use GNU coreutils.  seq was introduced in GNU and in plan9, but OSX is a BSD-like system.

Comment: Do you have a mac?  Check it out

Comment: oh, I believe you.  Doesn't make it any less ridiculous.